# AS3 array to Object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this array `var ar:Array = [234*256,558*698,256*784...];`
and i want to convert it to 2 arrays where first element (before *) goes in

```
var ar_x:Array;
```

and second element (after *) goes in other array

```
var ar_y:Array;
```

How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is element `234*256` or `"234*256"`?

Comment: Is `var ar:Array = [234*256,558*698,256*784...];` part of *text* or it is part of *script* ?

Comment: Its part of script. Its just x and y coordinates stored in MYSQL like that

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values at compile time just place them in the two separate arrays.

You can't separate them at runtime since when you place them like this :

```
 var ar:Array = [234*256,558*698,256*784];
```

The multiplication will be calculated and stored in the array and you will have this at runtime :

```
 var ar:Array = [59904,389484,200704];
```

On the other hand if the values are coming from an external source as strings "234*256" You can split that from the * symbol and store the two parts in separate arrays.

```
 var multiply:String = "234*256";
 var parts:Array = multiply.split("*");
 ar_x.push(parts[0]);
 ar_y.push(parts[1]);
```

Comment: Yes they are coming from mysql as strings, I am using AMFPHP to get them

Comment: If it is a string then you should be able to split it from "," to get the 234*256 part and then split from "*" to get the individual numbers.

Comment: split is a function of the String class, make sure you are calling it on a string object.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it!

Code looks like this:

```
var def_poss:Array = [def_pos[i][1],def_pos[i][2],def_pos[i][3],def_pos[i] [4],def_pos[i][5],def_pos[i][6],def_pos[i][7],def_pos[i][8],def_pos[i][9],def_pos[i][10],def_pos[i][11]];
}
for (var m:int=0;m<def_poss.length;m++)
{
    var temp_def:Array = def_poss.toString().split("*");
}
for (var n:int=0;n<temp_def.length;n++)
{
    var parts:Array = temp_def.toString().split(",");
    def_x.push(parts[0]);
    def_y.push(parts[1]);
    def_x.push(parts[2]);
    def_y.push(parts[3]);
    def_x.push(parts[4]);
    def_y.push(parts[5]);
    def_x.push(parts[6]);
    def_y.push(parts[7]);
    def_x.push(parts[8]);
    def_y.push(parts[9]);
    def_x.push(parts[10]);

}
```

First I have to `split ("*")` to get strange array `["255","255,586".....]`, then iterate thru that array and `split(",")` then push parts to separate arrays

Thanks for help!